# Kendo UI- Numeric Textbox: Style Issues

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css, kendo-ui

I'm working with an application that uses Kendo UI.
I've had to add some custom styling to the default Kedno UI theme.

However, I am having trouble with the positioning of the numeric text boxes, they do not want to sit in-line with other text boxes (see image below).

I've tried adding every combination of padding, margins(positive and negative) to all parts of the numeric textbox, but nothing I do can get it to sit like the other select boxes.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I've been a front-end developer for years, and have never struggled with something as much as this, nothing works.

[image: Numeric Text Box -Style Issue]

As you can see, the numeric text box sits a little low.

***My code looks like:***

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditAccount", "Finance", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "AccountDiv", OnSuccess = "AfterSaveAccount" }, new { id = "frmEditAccount" }))
{
     <div id="Process" class="label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsPaymentOnHold)
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.IsPaymentOnHold)
                  .DataTextField("Text")
                  .DataValueField("Value")
                  .BindTo(boolSelectListItems)
            )
        </div>
        <div class="label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsFinanceCharge)
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.IsFinanceCharge)
                  .DataTextField("Text")
                  .DataValueField("Value")
                  .BindTo(boolSelectListItems)
            )
        </div>
        <div class="label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FinanceChargePercent)
            @(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor<double>(m => m.FinanceChargePercent)
                  .Format("p")
                  .Decimals(4)
                  .Min(0.00)
                  .Max(0.99)
                  .Step(0.01)
                  .HtmlAttributes(new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                  )
        </div>
}
```

**It numeric textbox generates something like:**

```
        <div class="label">
              <label for="FinanceChargePercent">Finance Charge Rate</label>
              <span class="k-widget k-numerictextbox" style="">
                    <span class="k-numeric-wrap k-state-default">
                           <input aria-readonly="true" aria-disabled="false" readonly="readonly" style="display: inline;" tabindex="0" class="k-formatted-value k-input" type="text">
                           <input aria-readonly="true" aria-disabled="false" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemax="0.99" aria-valuemin="0" class="k-input" style="display: none;" role="spinbutton" data-role="numerictextbox" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Finance Charge Rate must be a number." id="FinanceChargePercent" max="0.99" min="0" name="FinanceChargePercent" readonly="readonly" step="0.01" value="0" type="text">
                        <span class="k-select"><span unselectable="on" class="k-link"><span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-n" title="Increase value">Increase value</span>
    </span>
   <span unselectable="on" class="k-link"><span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s" title="Decrease value">Decrease value</span>
</span>
</span>
</span>
</span>
<script>
jQuery(function() {       jQuery("#FinanceChargePercent").kendoNumericTextBox({"format":"p","decimals":4   });
});
</script>
 </div>
```

**My CSS:**

```
.label .k-numeric-wrap{
     padding:0 0  0 0;
     margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.label .k-numeric-wrap .k-input{
    padding:0 0  0 0;
    margin: 0 0  0 0;
}
.label .k-numerictextbox {
    max-width:160px!important;
    width:100%;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    margin:0 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: hm, got an fiddle? BTW, for reset margin and padding you can write: margin:0; padding:0;

Comment: No, to much work to make a fiddle for this one; I was hoping someone had a quick fix... And thanks, I realize that, but because I've been playing with every combination of margin/padding, I left them as 0 0 0 0 untill I found the solution.